# how can I confing Config.yaml in elasticalert?

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, elastalert

I am completely new in usung of `Elastcalert`. I am trying to use `Elasticalert` for striking email when no log is sent to `logstash` from my client server. I have successfully installed `Elastcalert` on my master server. However, when I run `elastalert-create-index` I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/elastalert-create-index", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('elastalert==0.1.21', 'console_scripts', 'elastalert-
create-index')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elastalert-0.1.21-
py2.7.egg/elastalert/create_index.py", line 77, in main
username = args.username if args.username else data.get('es_username')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

My `config.yaml` is as follow:

```
# This is the folder that contains the rule yaml files
# Any .yaml file will be loaded as a rule
rules_folder: example_rules

# How often ElastAlert will query Elasticsearch
# The unit can be anything from weeks to seconds
run_every:
  minutes: 1

# ElastAlert will buffer results from the most recent
# period of time, in case some log sources are not in real time
buffer_time:
  minutes: 15

# The Elasticsearch hostname for metadata writeback
# Note that every rule can have its own Elasticsearch host
es_host: localhost

# The Elasticsearch port
es_port: 9200

# The AWS region to use. Set this when using AWS-managed elasticsearch
#aws_region: us-east-1

# The AWS profile to use. Use this if you are using an aws-cli profile.
# See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-
started.html
# for details
#profile: test

# Optional URL prefix for Elasticsearch
#es_url_prefix: elasticsearch

# Connect with TLS to Elasticsearch
#use_ssl: True

# Verify TLS certificates
#verify_certs: True

# GET request with body is the default option for Elasticsearch.
# If it fails for some reason, you can pass 'GET', 'POST' or 'source'.
# See http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/connection.html?
highlight=send_get_body_as#transport
# for details
#es_send_get_body_as: GET

# Option basic-auth username and password for Elasticsearch
#es_username:
#es_password:

# Use SSL authentication with client certificates client_cert must be
# a pem file containing both cert and key for client
#verify_certs: True
#ca_certs: /path/to/cacert.pem
#client_cert: /path/to/client_cert.pem
#client_key: /path/to/client_key.key

# The index on es_host which is used for metadata storage
# This can be a unmapped index, but it is recommended that you run
# elastalert-create-index to set a mapping
writeback_index: elastalert_status

# If an alert fails for some reason, ElastAlert will retry
# sending the alert until this time period has elapsed
alert_time_limit:
  days: 2
```

Comment: Edited and formatted text for clarity, and add Python tag

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running elastalert-create-index without any arguments? It guides you through the setup process like this:

```
$>elastalert-create-index
Enter Elasticsearch host: localhost
Enter Elasticsearch port: 9200
Use SSL? t/f: f
Enter optional basic-auth username (or leave blank):
Enter optional basic-auth password (or leave blank):
Enter optional Elasticsearch URL prefix (prepends a string to the URL of every request):
New index name? (Default elastalert_status)
Name of existing index to copy? (Default None)
Elastic Version:6
Mapping used for string:{'type': 'keyword'}
New index elastalert_status created
Done!
```